# HTTP Accept Header meaning

Tags: http, http-headers, mime-types, content-negotiation

When a browser's Accept request header says something like the following:

```
Accept: application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
```

Does that mean that `application/xml`, `application/xhtml+xml`, and `text/html` all have a quality param of `0.9`?

Or does it mean that `application/xml` and `application/xhtml+xml` have the default (`q=1`) and `text/html` has the `q=0.9` param?

I'm assuming the former, but was hoping someone knew more definitively.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

No, if the [quality parameter](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1) is missing `q=1.0` is assumed:

> Each media-range MAY be followed by one or more accept-params, beginning with the "q" parameter for indicating a relative quality factor […] using the qvalue scale from 0 to 1 (section 3.9). The default value is q=1.

So the given value is to be interpreted as: “*application/xml*, *application/xhtml+xml*, and *image/png* are the preferred media types, but if they don’t exist, then send the *text/html* entity (`text/html;q=0.9`), and if that doesn’t exist, then send the *text/plain* entity (`text/plain;q=0.8`), and if that doesn’t exist, send an entity with any other media type (`*/*;q=0.5`).”

Comment: So to clarify, the `;q=0.9` only applies to `text/html` in the example? And as a corollary, `image/png` is also `q=1`?

Comment: I read the RFC but found it to be ambiguous, hence the question. So does the media-range fully end at each '`,`'?

Comment: There is a nice blog article on accept headers here: http://www.gethifi.com/blog/browser-rest-http-accept-headers Amongst other things the OP's question is adressed

Answer (score 0):

Verbally,this would be interpreted as "application/xml,application/xhtml+xml and image/png are the preferred media types,but if they do not exist,then send the text/html entity,and if that does not exist,send the text/plain entity,if that still does not exist,send an an entity with any other media type."