# REST API do different browsers render different Data interchange (JSON / XML)

Tags: xml, json, api, rest, browser

I am consuming a new RESTful API that a 3rd party has developed for a SSO API to one of my companies systems.

In the documentation it gives the following examples of data interchange, what I find strange is that for IE10 they say JSON is returned, and for Chrome and Firefox XML is returned.

I assummed one data interchange type would be used rather than multiple? Now when I parse the data I am going to have to check whether the type is JSON or XML first which doesnt seem correct? Shouldnt the RESTful API define one data interchange type rather than different ones for different browsers?

**Examples:**

*Chrome/Firefox:*

```
<VerifyTokenResponse xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MicrosSingleSignOnService.Models">
<Status>1</Status>
<TokenKey>test@testemail.com</TokenKey>
</VerifyTokenResponse>
```

*IE10 Json:*

```
{"Status":1,"TokenKey":"test@testemail.com"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would expect that the service would respect your [HTTP Accept header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331452/http-accept-header-meaning).

i.e you can specify which you prefer - XML or JSON

I would expect the response's `Content-Type` header to indicate what is actually returned to you.