# cURL PHP return weird string

Tags: php, curl

Recently, I want to scraping a website using CURL PHP. And the problem come. It return weird string combination and symbol. I really confused about it. I have set the encoding, both in header and declared it in curlopt.
Here is the coding I used to scrap.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate,br');
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

And this is the header I sent :

```
$header = [
    ':authority: www.airpaz.com',
    ':method: GET',
    ':path: $path,
    ':scheme: https',
    'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'cache-control: max-age=0',
    'referer: $referer',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1',
    'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36'
];
```

When I run it, it return exactly like the image below :

[image]

Can anyone tell what's the problem is? Thanks for your time. It will help me a lot

Comment: `accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8`. The last bit `*/*` says: unless you cannot serve me `text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng` I'll accept everything. And you got gzip because you accept it. Either don't, or ungzip the received content. If the server does not negotiate content correctly, you WILL HAVE TO ungzip the content.

Comment: Then, which part of the code I should change?

Comment: Isn't this obvious already? If you don't wish to accept *everything* drop the `*/*;q=0.8` from the `Accept` header.

Comment: I get that from the request header of the website. So, I think it should not be delete

Comment: You clearly miss the point of the Accept header.

Comment: Still not understand yet. Can u give me a reference for me to learn it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331452/http-accept-header-meaning

Comment: I have delete it, but still return like in the picture